# Prestashop 1.7 local environment and symfony server:run command

Tags: symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Prestashop 1.7+ is based on Symfony.

Symfony local environment debug mode means, that you runs command "php app/console (or bin/console at Symfony v3+) server:run" to start local webserver emulation and to view your project with local browser at localhost address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) without any WAMP, MAMP, XAMPP etc.

Also, local debug mode means, that you use app_dev.php prefix to view site in debug mode (with error and performance reports, profilers and other cool symfony features)

There is also commands in Symfony like "php app/console (or bin/console at Symfony v3+) doctrine:schema:validate)", to validate if Doctrine entities model correlate with Mysql database.

So my questions are:

1. Is Prestashop 1.7+ support "php app/console (or bin/console at Symfony v3+) server:run"?
2. Is Prestashop 1.7+ support Symfony app_dev.php debug mode?
3. Should I use "php app/console (or bin/console at Symfony v3+) doctrine:schema:validate)" to ensure that model and database are correct?
4. Are there any plans to use Twig instead of Smarty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prestashop 1.7 only uses very few symfony components mainly for the backoffice product listing and the modules page.

You cannot use any of the symfony commands as the app/console is not included.
Also even though going through the source files you will find doctrine the doctrine entities are not used anywhere so you cannot validate the schema.

Twig is only used in the backoffice on the 2 pages I mentioned earlier.

All in all you won't really stumble upon any symfony unless you go into the core code and you cannot (easily) include any bundles or use any Symfony commands.